# How can i include a html file in a div?

Tags: html

A lot of answers to my previous question have been suggestions that i stop using frames and iframes and use DIV. now my question is how to do you include a html file inside a DIV. it doesn't look straight forward.

Comment: Do you want to use Javascript on the client or use your server side language to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be very easy and simple.

Just load [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) on your page and use the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method and pass in the file you want to load.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { // this runs as soon as the page is ready (DOM is loaded)
   $("div") // selecting "div" (you can also select the element by its id or class like in css )
   .load("path/to/your/file.html") // load in the file specified
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Recreating frames using Javascript gives you most of the problems of frames, plus some different ones. **Not** recommended for core content loading.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would use some form of [include](http://bignosebird.com/ssi.shtml) [mechanism](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [template](http://template-toolkit.org/) [language](http://www.smarty.net/).

My preference would be to use Template-Toolkit and [the WRAPPER directive](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_WRAPPER) to wrap the content with the page template.

A div, however, is not a substitute for a frame. Use the markup most semantically appropriate for the content. Div is the last resort, for when there is an element with good semantics. (It is still a lot better than an element with the wrong semantics though).

Answer (score 1):

Start using a server-side language instead of just html files.

[PHP's include() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

```
include("myfile.php");
```

.NET example:

```
string file = Server.MapPath("myfile.txt");
if(System.IO.File.Exists(file)){
   Response.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file));
}
```

Keep in mind using javascript to load content gives you no SEO benefit. Using a server-side language will open the door for you to make your development go quicker anyway. You'll see the benefits immediately. You'll start using an include to pull in your header, footer, and probably content. Benefits would be that instead of digging through 100 html files to change 1 item in your header navigation, you'll only do it once and it'll immediately work through the rest of the site.

Answer (score 0):

To my ears, the suggestion to stop using frames/iframes seems to imply switching to Ajax.